# Keep value of input fields not processed by ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, input-field, preserve

I have a form which contains a table with two columns. Each row has a checkbox and an input field. While the checkbox is for deletion of the specific row, the input field is for (mass)editing of the values. Each input field uses bean validation. Additionally I have two buttons: one for 'delete' and one for 'save'. Everything is based on primefaces.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{backingBean.list}" var="entry" id="table">
        <p:column>
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{entry.flagDelete}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:inputText value="#{entry.value}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton value="save" actionListener="#{backingBean.save}" process="table @this" update="table" />

    <p:commandButton value="delete" actionListener="#{backingBean.delete}" process="@([type=checkbox]) @this" update="table" />
</h:form>
```

('process' equals 'execute' and 'update' equals 'render' in JSF 2)

Now it should be possible to delete the selected rows without the validation of the input fields. Therefore I used the primfaces ajax selectors (based on jQuery selector API) to select only the checkboxes, that should be processed during the ajax request. The values of the input fields are still send to the server but won't be processed.

The problem is the re-render of the table after the ajax request. I want the input fields to preserve the values that got entered before the delete-button was clicked (in case the user did not save his changes with the save-button). As those values got send to the server, this shouldn't be such a big deal (e.g. when the validation fails, I also get the last entered values). But actually I get the values, that are stored in the backing bean.
Is there any option/solution on how to achieve this?

Comment: then dont update whole table. Update only deleted row.

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan that's not possible in JSF, you should update the whole table.

Comment: Your problem is that you're updating the table even when the validation fails.

Comment: that's not possible in JSF??? **i beg to differ**

Comment: It can be done. Problem is that the commandButtons are outside the table. If the buttons were in a row, i.e. their parent component were a table row and you could get the client side id:  In the `actionListener` method of the commandButton, get a handle on the parent component and include it's id (which you'll get by `getClientId()` on the component) and manually include it in the partial view response for ajax updating by `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(/** the parent component id */)`.

Comment: Maybe I was not specific enough or I'am unable to unterstand your response @kolossus. I select some rows with the checkbox to delete them. The other rows may contain new values, that are not stored in the backing bean. While the selected rows should be deleted, the changed values should remain after re-rendering the table. The new table should not contain the delete rows (no problem) but it should contain the possible dirty data from the frontend. I have to skip the processing of the input fields or the validation may fail and you have to enter valid values just for deleting rows.

Comment: Here is what I mean, for the solution to work, you need to to be able to directly access the specific row of the datatable (using it's clientId) that you've made changes to. Your current setup cannot achieve that. So what I've proposed is for you to move the commandButtons into the table row so you can directly access the desired row. I'll post a more detailed answer

Comment: @kolossus now I understood what you mean. But how should this overcome my problem. Either I have to update the complete table after that or I have to tell JSF/Ajax to remove the single row in the frontend without re-rendering the whole table. I don't see, how that should work.

As I looked through the JSF implementation source, I see why my desired behavior won't work. Only the components mentioned in the execute/process attribute will be treated in the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase. There should be the possibility to apply these values without the other phases (JSF spec change I think...).